# Will any 30 pin replacement screen work with my hp stream 14 laptop

Tags: laptop, display

I guess I am wondering if there is as standard for the pinout on replacement screens for laptops. The screen is cracked on my hp stream 14 and the replacement screens are like $100. I found a dell screen that looks like it might fit for $30. It has the mounting hardware in the same spot and a 30 pin connector. But I'm not sure if it would work or not. Here is an ebay listing of the screen https://www.ebay.com/itm/165071166752 this is obviously for a dell laptop. Here is a listing of original screen for the hp stream https://www.ebay.com/itm/124044224309.

Is there a standard for the pinout or can 30 pin connectors be different? Do you think it is worth trying this dell screen or will it just not work? I don't feel like buying a new screen for $100 for this hp stream I could probably just buy the whold laptop used for that price.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 sides to consider.

Neither of those companies produce their hardware. Production is OEM:d, in case of laptops its Quanta, Compal and a few others. They don't produce the parts either, OEM manufacturers get those from other OEM manufacturers. En masse production necessarily requires a great deal of standardization. So there's a good chance those screens were produced by the same company. These aren't high-end products, at the end they might be even designed by the same firm.

But Dell and HP are still different companies. There's no benefit in having a standardization for Dell parts to work on HP products. In fact it can bring a loss, because people are apt to buy the cheaper Dell part if it fits. You don't need 30 pins to make a screen work, so it'd be logical for HP to use a couple of them for some extra control voltage (or something like that) just to ensure it can only be replaced by an "original HP part". You can only know if you dig deep into the design documentation, which obviously are very much confidential. Or you can test.

So your question boils down to: are you willing and able to invest $35 and the effort only to find out it doesn't work after all without losing sleep over it?